# get "read more" with custom DB query like you would with WP Query

Tags: posts, query-posts, read-more

I am using a custom database query to fetch posts.

In the post I have a break tag, which is displayed as `<!--more-->` in the database wp_posts table, but I can't get it to output like I would if I used `wp query`. It is basically ignored.

i tried using `apply_filters` like so, but to no avail:

```
<?php echo apply_filters("the_content", $post->post_content); ?>
```

I don't get either the "read more" anchor or the "read more" span tag in the post's content.

How can I get it with my custom query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<!-- more -->` tag isn't applied via the `the_content` filter, it's included in the `get_the_content()` function, which checks for the existence of the tag within the content using a regex and then outputs the more link appropriately. this output is filtered via the `the_content_more_link` filter, but since you're not using `get_the_content()` you won't be able to leverage that. you'll need to perform a similar regex replacement in our custom code. I would recommend filtering your more link via `the_content_more_link` as well, for compatibility. You can see the code `get_the_content()` uses here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L255